Nextjs Azure SQL Authentication
I'm building a fullstack application using NextJs and Azure SQL database. The database is Microsoft Entra-only authentication. I'm using NPM packages mssql for querying the database and @azure/msal-browser and @azure/msal-react for single sign on. For both dev (localhost) and production which is Azure Web App Services, I get this error message error: ConnectionError: Login failed for user ' '
Please assist me how I can fix this
db.js
const sql = require("mssql");

const server = process.env.AZURE_SQL_SERVER;
const database = process.env.AZURE_SQL_DATABASE;
const port = parseInt(process.env.AZURE_SQL_PORT);
const authenticationType = "azure-active-directory-default"


const config = {
  server,
  port,
  database,
  authentication: {
    authenticationType,
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
  },
};

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

async function connect() {
  try {
    await pool.connect();
    console.log("Connected to SQL Server!");
    return pool;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error connecting to SQL Server:", err);
    console.log("Auth Type: ", authenticationType);
    throw err; // Re-throw error for proper handling
  }
}

module.exports = {
  connect,
  pool,
};


Here is the full documentation I followed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase-sc%2Cuserassigned-sc%2Cnodejs%2Cdotnet-mysql-mi%2Cdotnet-postgres-mi%2Cvscode#how-do-i-add-the-managed-identity-to-an-azure-ad-group
I followed this document on microsoft page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase-sc%2Cuserassigned-sc%2Cnodejs%2Cdotnet-mysql-mi%2Cdotnet-postgres-mi%2Cvscode#how-do-i-add-the-managed-identity-to-an-azure-ad-group.
Also asked ChatGPT and Copilot but I got no solution

By Using Use SQL authentication I am able to connect to the Azure Sql Database.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416457/nodejs-mssql-connectionerror-login-failed-for-user


Error: ConnectionError: Login failed for user.

According to your information, you are trying to connect to an Azure SQL database from an app with managed identity authentication. The managed identity you're attempting to request a token for is not authorized to access the Azure database. That may be the reason for the login failed error. You will need to grant permissions to the managed identity using the CLI command below:
$groupid=(az ad group create --display-name myAzureSQLDBAccessGroup --mail-nickname myAzureSQLDBAccessGroup --query objectId --output tsv)
$msiobjectid=(az webapp identity show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app-name> --query principalId --output tsv)
az ad group member add --group $groupid --member-id $msiobjectid
az ad group member list -g $groupid

After granting permissions to the managed identity, you will be able to connect to the SQL database without any error. For more information, you can refer to the related MS Question.

@Kohn Solution Check if above provided solution works for you?
